# FPDF - PDF Form multilines and formatting

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm using **FPDF** to generate **PDF**. I use a PDF template created on Adobe Acrobat that include form inputs.

I've been using the following code to generate my pdf :

```
<?php

***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/

require('fpdm.php');

$fields = array(
    'date' => '07/07/2017',
    'names' => 'Something',

);

$pdf = new FPDM('Singlepage.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, true); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

It's working perfectly but now i'd like to add multiples lines to my `"names"` form. Something like `'names' => 'Someone1 \n Someone2`But I can't figure out how to do it.

On my pdf template, I added the "multiples lines" to the text input.

Do you have any idea ?

And then i'd like to format this text, so I could add bold, italic etc to the text

Comment: Using `"Someone1  \r\n  Someone2"` works perfectly for me.  Maybe the `\r` is needed.

Comment: Not working for me : [Image](http://www.noelshack.com/2017-28-4-1499960746-screenshot-9.png)

Comment: Try changing `$pdf->Load($fields, true);` to `$pdf->Load($fields, false); ` if you don't specifically need the fields to be utf-8

Comment: @WheatBeak They need to be as I will input some non latin characters

Comment: That's probably why it's printing the `\r\n`, maybe try to `utf8_encode()` any values with line breaks?

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the single quotes, change to double quotes and it will work (if the field is multi-line, of course):

```
$fields = array(
    'date' => '07/07/2017',
    'names' => "Something \n more",
);
```